# Кнопка закрытие блока

Tags: html, css

Как сделать кнопку с иконкой крестика, которая по клику закрывала бы какой-то всплывающий блок?

Comment: а сами пытались сделать? что конкретно не получилось?

Comment: К кнопке добавить `background-image`,  и в js прописать на событие onclick удаление нужного div   по его id или классу.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov У меня есть код кнопки <button id="closeButton" style="position: relative;bottom:122px;right: -550px;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url('img/icons/orders__close.png');" ;background-img:="" url(..="" img="" logo.png);="">close</button> Но нужно сделать, чтобы кнопка сама была подстроена под размер иконки

Comment: @Midnight но ведь это совсем другой вопрос, не про то как сделать закрытие окна, а про то как растянуть фон до размеров блока.

Answer (score 3):

Для изменения размера крестика стоит лишь изменить размер шрифта.

```css
/* Блок сообщения */
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* Крестик */
.closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  Тут Ваше сообщение
</div>
```

Пример взят с [этого сайта.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. `js` в тегах вопроса вы не указали, вот решение `html`+`css`.

ps: Однако как я понял проблема у вас не в этом. Погуглите `background-size: cover`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 16px;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: flex;
}

.modal {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: relative;
}

.modal label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 200%;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal label:hover {
  color: blue;
}

#openclose,
.modal-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

#openclose:checked~.modal-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#button {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="openclose" id="button">Открыть модальное окно</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="openclose">
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <label for="openclose">&times;</label>
  </div>
</div>
```